# How to power off (not reboot) Samsung S10+?

Tags: samsung, boot-loop, power-on

I appear to have bricked my S10+ by incorrectly flashing what I thought was stock firmware using heimdall and am now stuck in a boot-loop (that may be the wrong term).

The screen shows:

```
only official released binaries are allowed to be flashed (SYSTEM)

...

An error has occurred while updating the device software
...
```

If I hold volume-down + power long enough the screen goes black but then the phone immediately appears to reboot right back into the same screen.

I am hoping that I may be able to boot into download mode (volume-down + bixby + power ?) or recovery (volume-up + bixby + power ?) and try to salvage the situation.

But step one on all the guides I've found is to turn the power off, and I can't work out how to do that.

Comment: To turn the power off, you may try holding the power button for  30 seconds or more

Comment: @beeshyams even holding it for several minutes does nothing (and volume-down + power just reboots every 7 sec). However, I have discovered that volume-down + bixby and then plugging in usb may be getting me into download mode - adb can't see it but heimdall can flash files (although all the ones I've tried lead to the same error message)

Comment: still no idea how to power off other than making the battery go flat but have fixed the phone with odin in virtualbox

Comment: Sorry for that. I am clueless too

Comment: @beeshyams no worries. I don't need the information any more but if anyone finally answers, it may be useful to somebody in the future

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to get out of this is by getting into download mode by holding volume up+down and connect the phone to a PC using a USB cable then unplug the USB and let the phone in download mode to power off itself after 30 minutes (it will be like idle).

Comment: Thanks. I fixed my problem so not able to test this method. Hopefully it will help someone else.